# How can i get list of post based on your reading history - api medium

Tags: node.js, medium.com-publishing-api

Its posible get list of post *based on your reading history* using the [API Medium](https://developers.medium.com/)?

I read the repo but i dont see anything reference of this requirement

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you stated in your question, the documentation does not include an endpoint for a user's read history. The endpoint used to get your read history on the Medium site itself is likely private and only works for medium.com (which is probably a good thing given most people will allow access to their accounts without reading/realizing what they're giving up and having access to someones read history is a huge privacy issue). If you really need the read history, I think your best bet would be to [scrape the medium page](https://dev.to/aurelkurtula/introduction-to-web-scraping-with-nodejs-9h2) as the user you're trying to get the history of*.

*: Note that scrapping is likely in violation of Medium's ToS, do this at your own risk. It is **not** my fault if your account is suspended, closed, banned, etc.